# A better way to handle Activity restart on orientation change?

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

There is an activity which should not exist when a user leaves it. That's why it has `finish()` method in the `onStop`.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

However, this makes it restart each time the screen orientation changes. At the moment I handle this via Manifest Activity tag `android:configChanges="orientation"` and overriding method `onConfigurationChanged`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.someactivity);
    doAllInitializations();;
}
```

Is there a better way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop this orientation by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in your `activity tag` in the `manifest` file.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I thought that this attributes is a signal to app to throw an event when orientation changes which I handle in `onConfigurationChaged`. LOL